# Sticking to modular styling

Tags: css, module, bem

I have two modules:

A `.master-header` and a `.header-nav`

The `.header-nav` is inside the `.master-header` and is a simple nav:

```
<nav class="header-nav">
          <ul>
            <li class="active">
              <a href="/home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/here">Item</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/photos">Photos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/here">Item</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

In my `.header-nav` module I have the `height` of the `a`, `li` and `ul` to be 100% and then set the `height` of the `.header-nav` to be `100px` from within the `.master-header` as that's logically correct as to where the layout styles for it's children should belong.

Now, the problem comes as I wish to vertically center the text within the `a`'s. Line height is perfect for this but 100% won't work as 100% is the height of the font. `line-height: 100px` is the perfect thing to use to solve the issue but putting that inside the `.header-nav` module seems wrong as that's indicating that ALL `.header-nav`'s should be like that. I'd much rather it say something like 50% but I can't do `padding-top: 50%` as that's based on the width of the item.

Any thoughts on what to do?

Neil

Comment: Please supply a jsfiddle, so those willing to help you have something more than markup to play around with!

Comment: Not only that, but it's unclear what you want to achieve. It was alright up to "the perfect thing" - you meant you wanted something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/cfM7d/1/) - but then it got muddled.

Comment: If I'm guessing correctly, the solution is that there are other units besides `px` and `%`. How about `em`? In my example, the header-nav is 6em high, so half of that would be 3em. Would that work?

Comment: Or, as you seem to indicate, there are more elements with class `header-nav`, and your problem is that you want to pick out this specific one? In that case, just give it another class. You can give elements as many classes as you want in the class attribute: `class="header-nav yes-this-one"`

Comment: I didn't do a jsfiddle as it's not a sort of programming problem, more of a "where do I place this?" issue. line-height: 100px can solve my issue but I would have to place that line inside my .header-nav module and that doesn't seem like the right place according to the BEM module  methodology.

Answer (score -1):

You can use display: table-cell in order to achieve vertical alignment.

```
.header-nav {height: 100px}

.header-nav ul,
.header-nav li {height: 100%}

.header-nav ul {display: table;}
.header-nav li {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle}
```

[Check out this plunker for a working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/M3jKMXbSUwQZlID85cqQ)

Comment: Apart from CSS properties, it would be better to avoid "tag selectors" as they decrease page performance and make future support harder. More information is here http://bem.info/articles/yandex-frontend-dev/

Comment: Yandex is using tag selectors in bem on their website and different services.

Comment: Could you please explain why you are using `.b-center .b-tabs td` selector on your homepage?

Comment: I am not sure whose homepage is mentioned. If mine, I can explain if getting a link on it.

Comment: Actually the purpose of CSS part of BEM is to provide independent block components which is only possible with avoiding tag selectors. You can find explanations here http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/16/a-new-front-end-methodology-bem/